# igraph ggplot rStudio How can I make lines between nodes longer and add arrows? Also how can I make the legend smaller?

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I have a really wordy network plot. I am basically trying to have it function as a sort of flow chart. I am trying to make its aesthetics both functional and pleasing, but I am having a difficult time. The legend's text is way too large and there is not enough space in the network for everything to be spaced out properly. Also, I want to make the background a different color.

The only solutions I have been able to find, however, require the ggnet2 package, but when I try to install the ggnet2 package, it says I cannot install that on this version of rStudio. When I tried to update my rStudio, it says that I have the most recent version of rStudio. I do not know what else to try.

Any help would be much appreciated! This is my code:

```
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)

links <- data.frame(
 source=c("Pubertal Hormones, Timing, and Development","Pubertal Hormones, Timing, and Development","Pubertal Hormones, Timing, and Development","Pubertal Hormones, Timing, and Development","Genetic Vulnerability","Genetic Vulnerability","Temperament","Temperament","Depressogenic Vulnerability","Negative Cognitive Style","Negative Cognitive Style","Objectified Body Consciousness","Objectifed Body Consciousness","Rumination","Peer Sexual Harassment","Peer Sexual Harassment"),
 target=c("Genetic Vulnerability","Objectified Body Consciousness","Peer Sexual Harassment","Depressogenic Vulnerability","Temperament","Depressogenic Vulnerability","Negative Cognitive Style","Depressogenic Vulnerability","Gender Difference in Depression","Rumination","Depressogenic Vulnerability","Rumination","Depressogenic Vulnerability","Depressogenic Vulnerability","Objectified Body Consciousness","Gender Difference in Depression"),
 importance=(sample(1:4, 16, replace=T))
 )
V = c(links$source,
links$target) %>% 
unique() 

nodes <- data.frame(   name=V,   
carac=c(
rep("Biological Vulnerability",2),rep("Affective Vulnerability",3),rep("Cognitive Vulnerability",3),rep("Negative Life Events",2)) )

network <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=F) 

coul  <- brewer.pal(4, "Set3") 

my_color <- coul[as.numeric(as.factor(V(network)$carac))]

plot(network, vertex.color=my_color,vertex.shape=c("vrectangle"),vertex.size=c(150),vertex.label.cex=c(0.5))

legend("bottom", legend=levels(as.factor(V(network)$carac))  , col = coul , bty = "n", pch=20 , pt.cex = 3, cex = 1, text.col=coul , horiz = TRUE, inset = c(0.1, 0.1))
```

[image: this is what the network looks like!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small graph like this,  you can customize the layout so that things look nicer. We'll just step through the problems one at a time. Let's start from your plot statement, but let's make it reproducible by setting the random seed.

```
set.seed(123)
plot(network, vertex.color=my_color,vertex.shape=c("vrectangle"),
    vertex.size=c(150),vertex.label.cex=c(0.5))
```

[image: First plot]

The biggest problem is that the plot does not use all of the space in the graphics window. You can adjust that some with the `margin` parameter. When I do that, the boxes seem too big, so I will make them a bit smaller at the same time and also change the text size to match the new boxes.

```
set.seed(123)
LO = layout_nicely(network)

plot(network, layout=LO,  margin=-0.6, vertex.color=my_color,
    vertex.shape=c("vrectangle"), vertex.size=c(100),
    vertex.label.cex=c(0.7))
```

[image: Better margins and box size.]

OK, this is better, but there still are some problems. First, the box for "Pubertal Hormones, Timing, and Development" is too small. We can adjust that by using a vector of vertex sizes. When we change that, there are some other changes in the plot,  so let's just make that one change first.

```
VS = rep(100, vcount(network))
VS[1] = 150
plot(network, layout=LO,  margin=-0.7, vertex.color=my_color,
    vertex.shape=c("vrectangle"), vertex.size=VS,
    vertex.label.cex=c(0.7))
```

[image: Adjusted box size]

Next,  some of the boxes overlap. We can fix those by editing the layout matrix. This matrix is just the x,y coordinates at which to plot the nodes. I just looked at the matrix and adjusted the positions a little.

```
LO[1,]  = c(6.3,7.3)
LO[4,]  = c(5.4,6.7)
LO[5,]  = c(5,5.5)
LO[7,]  = c(7.4,6.8)
LO[8,]  = c(5.1,6.2)
LO[9,]  = c(5.2,8.4)
LO[10,] = c(7,8.3)

plot(network, layout=LO,  margin=-0.7, vertex.color=my_color,
    vertex.shape=c("vrectangle"), vertex.size=VS,
    vertex.label.cex=c(0.7))
```

[image: network with adjust node positions]

This is pretty good. More could be done,  but I think the method is clear, so I will leave any additional aesthetic adjustments of the nodes to you.

Now to finish up,  you wanted to adjust the background color. You can do that (before plotting) by setting `bg` using `par`.  The final version is:

```
par(bg="lightblue1")
plot(network, layout=LO,  margin=-0.7, vertex.color=my_color,
    vertex.shape=c("vrectangle"), vertex.size=VS,
    vertex.label.cex=c(0.7))
```

[image: Plot with background color]

Comment: hi! thank you so much! this is such a detailed walkthrough--i appreciate it so much and learned a lot!!! i have one question: when i put in some of this code, i get an error message that says "Error in i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(...)) : object 'LO' not found" I'm not sure what's wrong and why LO doesn't work? I tried googling and came up empty-handed. If you could explain why I might be getting that error, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doh.   I left out that line of code early on.  I will add in the LO line.

Comment: thank you so much! I just have one last question--I noticed in some other non-ggplot2 methods that you can add arrows to the ends of lines. I was wondering if that's possible with ggplot2 and if you could show me how to do that? when I searched elsewhere online, i could only find it done using a different method than ggplot2.

Comment: Sorry,  I am not a big `ggplot2` user. Here in `igraph`, you can use `directed=T` in your `graph_from_data_frame` statement.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!!! I learned a ton about igraph thanks to you!